# How is Molecular mass is the molecular weight?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atoms

Wikipedia says molecular weight is the mass!! I can't get it the weight is the mass times 10 so we cannot neglect that, because 10 amu is not equal to 1 amu

Comment: I don't understand your statement that "the weight is the mass times 10". If my answer doesn't help, please explain.

Comment: Weight is not simply "10 times mass". The weight in Newtons is 10 times the mass in kg.

Comment: Or more precisely, the weight in Newtons is the mass in kg times the acceleration due to gravity in $\mathrm{m~s^{-2}}$ which is approximately 10 at the earth's surface.

Comment: ah  yes, 9.81 m s^-2 rounds to 10. It was 9.82  in my 1970 physics book... ;-)

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/what-is-the-difference-between-weight-and-mass

Comment: Please do not change the premise of your question once it has recieved an answer with non-negligible score that would be invalidated. You can ask a new question any time.

Answer (score 3):

I'd absolutely consider **molecular mass** as the preferred term. Wikipedia even has the article with that title and the sloppily used term **molecular weight** redirects to **molecular mass**.

The point being that mass of some sample would be the same on earth as the Moon or Mars, but the weight would change. Since we're stuck on earth we really weigh samples in Earth's gravitational field of $9.806\mathrm{~m~s^{-2}}$. But all laboratory balances use mass units. The weight in Newtons is 9.806 (rounds to 10) times the mass in kg. In science we don't like standard units that depend on arbitrary standards, and the gravity of the earth is arbitrary value on a galactic scale. Gravity isn't even constant over the surface of the earth. Read about how the [meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre) has been standardized. Fascinating to me.

Comment: He doesn't get the difference between weight and mass. He thinks that an object with a mass of 1 kg has a weight of 10 kg.

Comment: I very much refuse to accept that the term molecular weight is the same as molecular mass. This is not a preference, the first expression is just plain wrong. Mass and weight are two completely different things. In sloppy spoken words we might understand what is meant; it might be used very often, even by teachers and professors and people who should know better; but it is incorrect nevertheless. If you refer to a mass of any kind, don't call it weight. Sorry, but I have to give it a down vote.

Comment: @Martin - Ok, you're right this is supposed to answers should be educating so I reworded the first part.

Comment: @orthocresol An object with a mass of 1 kg has a weight of 1 kg-wt but in my question I converted it to Newton that doesn't alter the point of the question! Why is atomic weight is referred to as atomic mass!? despite they both have different dimensions one has a mass dimension the other has a force dimension

Comment: The correct and internationally standardized name for this quantity is “relative molecular mass”. For historical reasons, IUPAC accepts the use of the special name “molecular weight” for the quantity relative molecular mass. However, the use of this traditional name is deprecated. Also note that the quantity relative molecular mass is dimensionless and thus it is not to be confused with the quantity molar mass $M$ (with the usually used unit $\mathrm{g/mol}$).

Comment: @MaxW The current Wikipedia article on “molecular mass” contains several severe mistakes. In particular, the article confuses various quantities and units.

Comment: @Loong - Thanks! I looked at the discussion on the wikipedia article and it shows quite a bit of bantering about all of this. IUPAC is certainly the dog and wikipedia the tail on this.

Comment: @AhmedElsawy well, if you were clear about the difference between weight and mass, you would not have written that "weight is the mass times 10", and you would not have referred to a "weight" of 10 amu, because amu is actually a unit of mass.

Comment: @Ahmed-Elsawy - the confusion in the wikipedia article is about one atom or a mole of atoms is being considered. The Wikipedia article is inconsistent with IUPAC who is the definitive source on terminology.

Comment: @orthocresol then tell me why atomic weight is measured in amu?

Comment: @AhmedElsawy If you took the trouble to read everyone else's comments, you would see that "atomic weight" is just an old, imprecise synonym for "atomic mass".

Comment: @orthocresol this answer is not satisfying

Comment: Wikipedia is inconsistent. They sometimes use the term "molecular mass" to be what IUPAC calls the “relative molecular mass” (i.e. grams/mole). and sometimes Wikipedia is using "molecular mass" to mean the weight of one molecule which is measured in amu.

Comment: @Ahmed your comment is not satisfying. I would ask another question only after I've read what I should've.